# Sails autoCreatedAt inserting datetime 5 hours back form current

Tags: sails.js

I am using sails autoCreatedAt to store creation date in table, but it is storing different values in local and remote server.

In local the the current datetime is stored but in remote server the time stored is 5:30 hours back from current.

I am unable to find what is the issue,why is this happening.

Please help me out..

Comment: What DB did you use? MySQL Date or Datetime type have no timezone state, so it's not good to save date record except make sure host timezone set to UTC.

Comment: can you help me with how to set default time zone for sails app

Comment: Javacript has no default timezone setting for an app like Java did. You can use `Date.UTC` factory to do that like this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC). You can also use `moment.js` to easily manipulate date.

But it's just an expectation, what DB actually did you use? It's better to save date as timestamp milliseconds as `Long`, but it's not queryable as `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting  `process.env.TZ = 'UTC'; //whatever timezone you want`

in `config/bootstrap.js`

Answer (score 0):

One posible answer could be this:

Use UTC and manage it in your code with moment.JS

1. Set `autoCreatedAt: false` and `autoUpdatedAt: false` on the model
2. Then add `createdAt` and `updatedAt` attributes to each collection and manage them like any other attribute.
3. Using the [lifecycle callbacks](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks) `afterCreate` and `afterUpdate` that sails provide us you can force it to do it automatically.

What I mean is something like this:

```
/**
* User.js
*/

module.exports = {

    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,

    attributes:
    {
        email               : { type: 'email', required: true, unique: true },
        created_At      : { type: 'datetime' },
        updated_At      : { type: 'datetime' }
    },

    afterCreate: function (attrs, cb)
    {
        var date = moment(new Date()).locale('es').tz('America/Mexico_City').format();

        attrs.created_At = date;

        return cb();
    },

    afterUpdate: function (attrs, cb)
    {
        var date = moment(new Date()).locale('es').tz('America/Mexico_City').format();

        attrs.updated_At = date;

        return cb();
    }

};
```

In the example I'm using `Mexico City` timezone just you need to adjust yours.

I hope it could be useful.